# Which adaptation of Richard II the John of Gaunt's speech played in Tom Hiddleston's Jaguar Commercial at the beginning comes from?

Tags: identification-request, william-shakespeare, richard-ii

Starring Tom Hiddleston, at the beginning of this Jaguar advertisement: [Art Of Villainy With Tom Hiddleston - Jaguar Ad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGas3e7p_9A), a recording of John of Gaunt's speech (This royal throne of kings, this scepter’d isle, this earth...) in Shakespeare's Richard II is played and paused; and a minite later, Tom Hiddleston finished the speech himself (This happy breed of men, this little world...).

The speech in the old recording seems to be delivered in traditional RP accent, and sounds very emotional and moving.

My question is: does anyone know where this recording comes from? From which adaptation of film, or TV series, or radio dramatisation? Who played the role John of Gaunt in this adaptation?

Comment: I think it's [Edgar Wreford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Wreford) from "[An Age of Kings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Age_of_Kings)" (1960). See [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQQyyMyTHa0).

Comment: @GarethRees perhaps covert that comment to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Gareth Rees's comment, this seems to be [Edgar Wreford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Wreford) from "[An Age of Kings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Age_of_Kings)" in 1960.

### YouTube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQQyyMyTHa0

Comment: Converting comment to answer